# How to execute curl commands in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, guzzle

I have a curl command

```
curl -i -k https://anAddress.com/web/publication/add -d '{"title”:"uniqueIdxxxxxxx"}' -uexpress:Test0099887766 -H"Content-Type: application/json" -X POST
```

I need to run this CURL command in laravel. I tried using guzzle:

```
$client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://annAddress.com/web/publication/add', [
            'form_params' => [
                'title' => 'xc123',
            ]
        ]);

        $result= $res->getBody();
        dd($result);
```

but I just get an error:

```
TooManyRedirectsException in RedirectMiddleware.php line 141:
Will not follow more than 5 redirects
```

Comment: It looks like the response sends a redirect to the same page. What's the full response of the curl command?

Comment: I was glad to run into this question because I hadn't even heard of Guzzle. Its docs are here: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle  I will try using this in Laravel whenever I need to post data to a URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $url = 'Your API URL';

  $ch = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $output = curl_exec ($ch);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $http_result = $info ['http_code'];
  curl_close ($ch);
```

Try like this. Good luck

Comment: Using guzzle is a lot better, no need to use the curl_* functions